Spring Boot CORS JUnit Test Fails While Curl Works
Relevant parts of pom.xml:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Cors Configuration:
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsConfig  {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter()  {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost", //
                "https://test.example.org/", //
                "https://stage.example.org", //
                "https://example.org"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}

Running the application and running curl commands works
$ curl -v -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: https://www.example.com" 
http://localhost:8080/my-api/my-endpoint

As expected, returns: Invalid CORS request* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
$ curl -v -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://localhost" 
http://localhost:8080/my-api/my-endpoint

As expected, returns the proper JSON response
However, this JUnit test fails:
@Test
void corsDeniesExampleDotCom() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/my-endpoint") //
            .header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET") //
            .header("Origin", "http://example.com")) //
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden()) //
            .andDo(print()) //
            .andReturn();
    
}

 Status expected:<403> but was:<200>

How can I make this JUnit test work?
Notes:
I have looked at Testing CORs in SpringBootTest and it is an old question, and the provided answers do not work.
